# Write a native code as background to get data from server

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, go

I have created a Go server which communicate well with my flutter code and I can get messages from the server but only when my app is running
My problem is that if the app is not running I can’t get data from the server
So I went though the internet and asked some friends about the problem All I got
It’s I need to implement native code to my Go server so from native code I will create a channel to my dart file
But I don’t know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Services` on Android side (read more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)). It feature works only on Android because iOS limits background activity of the app. You need to create a service and do your work in him. Service can be running as separate process and live after user close your app.